# Change attribute value in DOM element using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example

```
<text class="more" x=5>
```

Can I able to change the value of "**X**" using jquery or javascript

Comment: `$('text').attr('x', newvalue)`

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: vanilla: element.setAttribute('x', 'val')

Comment: setAttribute in plain javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try this**

```
$('text').attr('x','78')
```

Answer (score 5):

Why to use JQuery for simple tasks?

```
document.querySelector('text').setAttribute('x', '25');
```

Or, a bit more performant:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].setAttribute('x', '25')
```

Answer (score 1):

$('.more').attr('x', 'value you want');

Answer (score 1):

For any standard HTML attribute, you can update the attribute using `setAttribute`.

**But...** if you want to manipulate *custom attributes* like `x`, you can use the HTML5 `data-*` attribute and javascript `.dataset` instead:

**Eg.**

To change

```
<text class="more" title="Using HTML5 data-* attributes" data-x="5">
```

to

```
<text class="more" title="Using HTML5 data-* attributes" data-x="8">
```

You can use the following javascript:

```
var moreText = document.getElementsByClassName('more')[0];
var x = parseInt(moreText.dataset.x);
var x = x + 3;
moreText.dataset.x = x;
```

---

The traditional approach (for non-data-* elements) is:

```
var moreText = document.getElementsByClassName('more')[0];
var newTitle = 'Using HTML5 custom data-* attributes';
moreText.setAttribute('title',newTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax**: `$(selector).attr(attribute,value);`

**Example** :

```
$('.more').attr('x','Update New Value');  //Update value

$('.more').attr('x');  //Get attribute Value
```

```js
$('.more').attr('x', '51'); // page load update value

$('#Newvalue').click(function() {
  var newValue = $('.more').attr('x'); // Get Value attr 'X'
  alert(newValue);
  console.log(newValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<text class="more" x=5>

  <input type="button" id="Newvalue" value="Get New Value" />
```

Comment: idk, I upvote to compensate because sometimes happens also to me lol

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
1.   $('.more').attr('x',15);
```

or

```
 2. $("text").attr('x',25)
```